# Linker complains about -fPIE yet unable to fix

Tags: c++, linker, qt5, qmake, linker-flags

I have a program which compiles and links fine on many different linux distros.  Today I tried to build on Ubuntu 22 and got the error below on the linking step.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /commerciallibs/senselockAPI/Linux_X64/Ubuntu/libsenseEIV.a(s4wf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:1005: autocommander] Error 1
```

I tried cleaning and recompiling with -fPIE flag, but the error remains.  I am using C++17 and Qt5/QMake on Ubuntu 22 x86_64.  The library file above (libsenseEIV.a) is a commercial library which is precompiled, so I cannot make any changes to it.

I am building an executable (not an SO).  Can someone explain what is causing the error and how to fix it?

Comment: probably libsenseEIV is not a PIE compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with -fpie when trying to link in assembly code and I needed to use -fno-pie on the other stuff to get it to work.

nasm -felf64 myproc.asm
gcc -fno-pie myprog.c myproc.o -o myprog

I still don't really know what the benefit of pie is in the first place.

Comment: This actually works so I'm tempted to accept the answer (thanks!).  But I would really love for someone to explain WHY it works, and what's happening here

Comment: TSG  something something independent position code can run wherever in memory it's loaded, but I fail to see how that's an advantage except on some ancient computer without a memory management unit. I remember reading years ago how windows DLL's always had the "same address" so they were threshing  particular cache lines.

Comment: Looks like the commercial library is not compiled with PIE/PIC, so upon linking it's mixing PIC/PIE and non-PIC/PIE code.  Adding the no-pie option to the linker results in successful non PIE/PIC executable creation.   Without the option the linker complains that it cannot create a PIE/PIC executable because one of the modules being linked is not PIE/PIC.  Hence the warning message suggesting recompiling (but it is implicitly referring to the commercial module).  Would be nice if the error were more specific and clear.

Comment: I ran into a situation a couple days ago where -fno-pie didn't work either, and it turns out that -no-pie fixed that.